# how to define an eclipse mask formatted text field?

Tags: java, swing, jformattedtextfield

I need to put a masked formatted text field in my jframe, i put it like this

```
MaskFormatter mask = new MaskFormatter("########/##");
JFormattedTextField txtName = new JFormattedTextField(mask);
```

but when I run the program the textField is empty and it doesn't save it on data base

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [MaskFormatter documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/text/MaskFormatter.html) we can see that

> `#` Any valid number, uses `Character.isDigit`.

If you want to accept text (letters and digits) use

> `A` Any character or number (`Character.isLetter` or `Character.isDigit`)
>   `*` Anything

You may also want to use this form

```
JFormattedTextField txtName = new JFormattedTextField();
MaskFormatter mask = new MaskFormatter("########/##");
mask.install(txtName);
```

Comment: now the slash appears but it still not saved on the data base

Comment: @HindDev also by "the slash appears" you mean that only splash appears or rest of characters you typed also, but they are not saved in DB?

Comment: before i made a simple text field it worked, i changed just the component and it's name

Comment: @HindDev I am not sure what you mean. I would like to know if with my linked code you are able to print current content of that field or not. Saving to database is not important now because we need to make sure that we are actually getting some value before we try to save it.

Comment: the field appears with mask like this "________/__" I can write in it, it accept only numbers perfectly or i heard a sonor bip, but when i clic save it create the record with all new fields only this mask field is empty

Comment: @HindDev If you want to be able to write any character except digit you need to change `#` mask into something else since `#` can accept only digits. For instance, if you want to accept any character your mask could look like `********/**`.

Comment: @HindDev Now you said "*I can write in it, it accept only numbers perfectly*" are you able to see these numbers when you click button?

Comment: that was before, you told me to add "mask.install(txtName);" i did it and it accept the digits like i wanted, now i need only that my data be saved

Answer (score 2):

You say that it does not accept the text.

But # indicates only numbers

Here is a table extracted from: http://www.javalobby.org/java/forums/t48584.html

**Character     Description**

#  Any valid number, uses Character.isDigit .

'   Escape character, used to escape any of the special formatting characters.

U   Any character ( Character.isLetter ). All lowercase letters are mapped to upper case.

L   Any character ( Character.isLetter ). All upper case letters are mapped to lower case.

A   Any character or number ( Character.isLetter or Character.isDigit )

?   Any character ( Character.isLetter ).

*  Anything.

H   Any hex character (0-9, a-f or A-F).

Comment: it doesn't accept any thing i wrote a nuber like shown on the mask it doesn't appear in my data base the field empty

Comment: @HindDev one step at a time, nothing in your code mentions a database, so if you think your question has more context, update it. To me, both answers are perfectly valid given the input you gave