# Is there a way to ignore backspace key in java?

Tags: java

Whenever I press backspace in the text box this code is triggered.

```
private void txtAgeKeyTyped(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt) {                                
        char agetext= evt.getKeyChar();
        if(!(Character.isDigit(agetext))){
            evt.consume();
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Age is only written in Numbers!");
        }
}
```

It should only be triggered if I typed Alphabets instead of Numbers only.

For some reason it is triggering whenever I press the Backspace Key.

Is there a way for me to use backspace without triggering this block of code?

I'm sorry this is the first time i fiddled with Key Events

Comment: What method is it? Why is it triggering? Please, add some details to your question!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15693904/java-keylistener-keytyped-backspace-esc-as-input

Comment: if i want to delete characters using backspace in textbox the message "age is only written in numbers!" appears 

i used KeyTyped in Netbeans

Comment: @user3647634 well is the backspace key considered a digit? No, it is not. That's why your if statement evaluates to true and you see "*age is only written in numbers!*".

Comment: @JonnyHenly I think the OP knew that already. That's why he/she is trying to make backspace not trigger the method.

Comment: Use [`Character.isLetter(...)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#isLetter(char)) instead of `isDigit(...)` and remove the leading negation from the if staement. So `if(!(Character.isDigit(agetext)))` becomes `if(Character.isLetter(agetext)))`.

Answer (score 4):

The backspace character is just `\b`. As you can see, the `VK_BACK_SPACE` constant is defined like this:

```
public static final int VK_BACK_SPACE     = '\b';
```

The constant is defined in the `java.awt.event.KeyEvent` class btw. If you use IntelliJ it will automatically and statically import it for you.

You can check whether `agetext` is `\b`. If it is, return from the method:

```
private void txtAgeKeyTyped(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt) {   
    char agetext= evt.getKeyChar();
    if (agetext == VK_BACK_SPACE) return;
    if(!(Character.isDigit(agetext))){
        evt.consume();
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Age is only written in Numbers!");
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there another way to ignore Backspace ?

Comment: As far as I'm concerned, no @user3647634

Comment: @user3647634 Check this out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32018509/how-to-define-an-eclipse-mask-formatted-text-field It might help you.